# How can I adjust this code to include vertexes in the for loops?

Tags: for-loop, vertex, p5.js

//Study and use beginShape() and endShape() to draw 3 separate sketches. Each sketch must contain vertices ( vertex() ). tools you will need: beginShape(), endShape(), vertex(), for loop.

//We are supposed to be making Moire patterns. I have gotten the desired result with the code below but it does not include vertexes as the assignment asks. How can I edit adjust this code to include vertices but give the same output?

```
var theta = 0.0;
var circWidthMultiplier = 17.5;
var circHeightMultiplier = 12.5;
var rectWidthMultiplier = 12.5;
var rectHeightMultiplier =17.5;
var rotationSpeed = 0.005;
function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth,windowHeight);
  rectMode(CENTER);
}

function draw() {
  background(100);
  noFill();

  push();
  beginShape();
  translate(width/2, height/2);
  for(var i =0; i < 50; i+=5){
    ellipse(0, 0,
    i*rectWidthMultiplier,
    i*rectHeightMultiplier);
  }
  endShape();
  pop();


  push();
  beginShape();
  translate(width/2, height/2);
  rotate(theta);
  for(var i =0; i < 50; i+=5){
    ellipse(0, 0,
    i*circWidthMultiplier,
    i*circHeightMultiplier);
  }
  endShape();

  pop();
  beginShape();
  translate(width/2, height/2);
  for(var i =0; i < 50; i+=2){
    rect(0, 0,
    i*circWidthMultiplier,
    i*circHeightMultiplier);
  }
  endShape();
  pop();
  theta += rotationSpeed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now you're using functions like `ellipse()` and `rect()` to draw your shapes. You **could** use `beginShape()`, `vertex()`, and `endShape()` to draw your shapes instead.

Start with replacing the `rect()` function. You already know the position and size of the rectangle. So it should be pretty easy to replace that with four calls to the `vertex()` function.

The circles are a little bit trickier, but still doable. You'd need to use basic trigonometry to figure out the vertexes around the circle. Google is your friend here.

But honestly, this seems a little bit pointless. Why bother using `vertex()` to draw shapes that Processing already draws for you? You might want to check with your instructor to make sure that you're understanding the assignment correctly.